# Why is Amphotericin B insoluble in water in the pH range that makes it zwitterionic?

Tags: acid-base, solubility, drugs, medicinal-chemistry

Here is the structure of Amphotericin B, with its carboxylic acid and amine groups circled in red:
[image]

According to [this source](http://www.ulab360.com/files/prod/manuals/201209/18/32986001.pdf), The carboxylic acid group has a pKa of 5.5 and the amine group has a pKa of 10. It says there and in other sources as well that Amphotericin B is insoluble in water in the pH range of 6-7, but is more soluble in pH < 2 or > 11.

My question is why is it that in a pH range **between the pKa values**, where both the carboxylic group and the amine group are charged (a *zwitterionic state*), the molecule is considered insoluble in water? With both groups charged, I would assume solubility should be **higher** then when only one of them is charged, as is the case in pH < 2 or > 11.

I couldn't find anything about this issue online. I went back to basic organic chemistry textbooks and read about zwitterions, isoelectric points etc., but couldn't find anything useful regarding such a complex molecule as Amphotericin B. I did find [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139090/why-are-amino-acids-least-soluble-at-isoelectric-point) here on Chemistry.SE regarding water solubility of amino acids in their zwitterionic state, but the answer given there does not suffice for me, as I still do not understand why would zero net charge mean lower solubility, when we have **two** charged moieties on top of many hydroxyl groups that also contribute plenty to water solubility?

Comment: Molecules with no net charge aggregate and crystallize more easily than those that are charged and need a counter ion. Non polar amino acids like valine are also much less soluble as zwitterions than as cations or anions

Comment: Do molecules with no net charge necessarily not require counter ions? It seems that for Amphotericin B, the charged groups are not very close to each other, so doesn't each of them require a counter ion of its own?

Comment: You are asking too much when expect to dissolve a compound with at least 14 carbon non-polar chain (without a counter ion).  Even, sodium dodecyl sulfate with only 12 carbon and a counter ion has critical micellar concentration, meaning not completely soluble.

Comment: But why is it more soluble in extreme pH values when it is in ionic state?

Comment: One would need a little ball & stick model but I suspect it can even be an internal salt as for the charged sites can be brought in contact